# get as name of column while selecting

Tags: php, mysql

I have select code like this:

```
mysql_query('
  SELECT id, date, ip, page, get, referer 
  FROM iplog ORDER BY id DESC
');
```

My problem is, name of column called get causes error.

When I change column name in both here and in database, error is gone. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show the error as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use backquotes for reserved words (or names with characters like spaces):

```
SELECT id, date, ip, page, `get`, referer FROM iplog ORDER BY id DESC
```

`get` is a reserved word in MySQL 5.7.  The list is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/reserved-words.html).  It starts appearing as a reserved word in MySQL 5.6.

Answer (score 0):

One of these is probably a reserved word for your database.  If you cannot detemrine which, nor want to, wrap each name in backticks like:

```
`date`
```

Answer (score 0):

put the names in backticks like

```
`get`
```

Then your query will be look like:

```
mysql_query('
  SELECT id, date, ip, page, `get`, referer 
  FROM iplog ORDER BY id DESC
');
```

because get is a keyword/reserve word in mysql